# Google Analytics User ID - Is it ok to use a company name?

Tags: google-analytics

From the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy

Using User ID to 'allow Google to personally identify an individual' is bad.

My question is, can I use a company name in this ID field (as all of our users are companies and have paid accounts), as this would make reports easier to read ?

Answer (score 1):

What they normally mean is it cant be someone's email because google could track that.  It is fine to use an internal Id that only you and your company know of.  Assuming users are logging into your site you should have a primary key for each user.  You could send that as User id to identify each user.

Remember the User Id field is used internally to aggregate data. Its not something you are going to see.  Think of it as a session id over multiple sessions.  I get a session id when I first hit your site I spend five minutes surfing around the system knows it was me in that five minutes because of the session id.  Using User id is the same only it can continue over multiple sessions so you will know its me coming back tomorrow or next week.

By sending company name all the users who are accessing your site for that company are going to aggregated together.

Answer (score 0):

there can be someday with same company names!(say two different branches)

Better use company name + some number(or timestamp)// readable & unique

Examples: GOOGL1473325669452, APPLE1473325690779